# WCF call to an Axis2 webservice - System.ServiceModel.FaultException: BusinessObject

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm writing a .Net C# Web service that is used to call a remote Axis2 web service at one of our suppliers using WS-Security

It has to be hosted as a COM-visible DLL file because I'm actually using Coldfusion 9 as the main Application Server and I've dropped to .Net as I don't really want to use Java as Coldfusion 9 only supports Axis 1.1 and I've loads of other web services running in there and I don't want problems with class loading affecting those services

My .Net ability is limited at best as I'm really a Java monkey but I've used it in the past to create web services when Coldfusion doesn't like talking to the remote web service.

The problem I'm having with this one seems to be around the call to the service, it's throwing the following error

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: BusinessObject:
>   Q1SearchOrderReferenceType@67af67af (Reference=Q1TextType@67c067c0,
>   AllocatedBy=Q1TextType@67dd67dd)

Server stack trace:

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:

> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   TCAB2BWebService.ForwardOrder(ForwardOrderRequest request)    at
>   uk.co.etsos.coal.CoalGateway.RequestCoal(CoalOrderDetails
>   orderDetails)

The call I'm making is

```
this.client.Open();

Q1SearchOrderType searchRequest = setCoalOrderDetails(orderDetails);
Q1SearchProductReferenceType1 productReference;

XMLHelper<Q1SearchOrderType> requestXMLHelper = new XMLHelper<Q1SearchOrderType>(baseDirectory);
requestXMLHelper.Save(searchRequest, orderDetails.MessageId, orderDetails.SecurityId, "Request");

Q1SearchOrderReferenceType1 response = this.client.ForwardOrder(searchRequest, out     productReference);
CoalUtil.writeToLogFile(ObjectInspector.Dump(response).ToString(), this.logFile);
CoalUtil.writeToLogFile(ObjectInspector.Dump(productReference).ToString(), this.logFile);
```

It never reaches the writeToLogFile - so the error is being thrown on the ForwardOrder, which was generated by svcutil from the WSDL

```
public Q1SearchOrderReferenceType1 ForwardOrder(Q1SearchOrderType SearchOrder, out Q1SearchProductReferenceType1 SearchProductReference)
{
    ForwardOrderRequest inValue = new ForwardOrderRequest();
    inValue.SearchOrder = SearchOrder;
    ForwardOrderResponse retVal = ((TCAB2BWebService)(this)).ForwardOrder(inValue);
    SearchProductReference = retVal.SearchProductReference;
    return retVal.SearchOrderReference;
}
```

I'm completely stuck as to what on earth I'm doing wrong and any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: `FaultException` means that the _server_ returned a SOAP Fault.

Comment: OK thank you - I'll take that back to the remote integration team and try and get some feedback what went wrong